# Let $-1<t<0$. Is there a $ t$ such that

Tags: inequality

Let $-1<t<0$. Is there $t$ such that for all positive integers $n>c$($c$ is a positive integer depends on $t$)

$n^t - (n+1)^t > 1/n$

Comment: It is possible to say so if it's true. Is it ?

 t has to be negative. The t you picked is clearly not

Comment: I deleted it. It was just an example. The point is, is there a such $t$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Let $t=-s$ with $0<s<1$.
Note that for all $n>1$ we have $n>n^s\iff \frac1{n^s}>\frac1n\iff n^t>\frac1n$. It follows that $n^t+(n+1)^t>n^t>\frac1n$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example if you take $t=-\frac{1}{2}$, then your inequality holds for all n>.5 (in fact its something like .419643). I used wolfram alpha for the computation, you can check it out yourself.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%28n%29%2B1%2Fsqrt%28n%2B1%29%3E1%2Fn

Comment: Thank you. But it was my mistake. It's not $n^t + (n+1)^t > 1/n$ . It's $n^t - (n+1)^t > 1/n$